# Cannot connect to oracle server from c#

Tags: c#, oracle10g

I have oracle 10g Express Edition installed and I'm trying to connect to it from C#.

I've created a ODBC Data Source called MyOracle from ODBC Data Source Administrator.

I'm using Windows XP and Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition.

Here's my code:

```
string connString = "dsn=MyOracle;User=user;Password=pass";

        OdbcConnection connection = null;
        OdbcCommand command = null;
        OdbcDataReader reader = null;

        try
        {
            connection = new OdbcConnection(connString);

            connection.Open();

            connection.Close();

            connection.Dispose();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("StackTrace:\n\n{0}\n",ex.StackTrace));

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Message:\n\n{0}\n", ex.Message));
        }
```

The console output tells me that the problem is at connection.Open();

Here's the output:

[image: Console Error msg]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your connection string to the following:

```
string connString = "DSN=MyOracle;UID=user;PWD=pass;Integrated Security=no;";
```

Comment: Now I get ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft] [ODBC Driver Manager] Data Source name not found and no default driver specified.